# Is MacKeeper a contoversial App that new Apple Users should be educated to stay away from?

Tags: applications

I see adverts for this particular app all over the place. Is it true that people should stay well away from it, as it could potentially do more harm than good to your Apple Computer, and to your wallet!!

Comment: Where does it say "that people should stay well away from it" ?

Comment: it doesnt thats my own interpretation, from what i've gathered, and I would just like views from Seasoned Apple Users. What is your experience ?

Comment: From this sites FAQ "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." I think we could anwser if you had a specific issue about Mackeeper but not an open ended query

Comment: OK fine. I'll remember that :)

Comment: How do you go from the front page to the second page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly true that the app is controversial - search the Apple Discussions site for more on that - and while there were certainly issues with early versions current versions are reported better.

However, there are many with very significant reservations about the sales tactics the company uses - pop-ups, paid-for recommendations on review sites etc - and that its uninstaller didn't work for many versions, so users kept getting further advertisements, allied with the  facts that the things the app claims to do are either a: unnecessary or b: can be done with free or cheaper alternatives means that the app undeniably has a bad name with many Mac users.

And again, for citation: search the Apple Discussions site for much, much more about this app.

Comment: Thankyou for your response terrydev, what you have described fully concurs with what I have read & the reason I asked the question in the first place. The company that owns it even bought a similar sounding domain name to that of the free antivirus clamxav and when people tried to download clamxav (from this other unofficial site) they were redirected to download Mackeeper. Perhaps people who are new to Apple computers should be made wary especially as they advertise all over the place.

Comment: The way the product is advertised also looks very attractive

Comment: @Simon, I would believe that is the purpose of advertising :)

Comment: @Gerry, I agree advertising is a very powerful medium :)